# How to Insert a Row at a specific Positions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Excel workbook, where I have defined series of Numbers in a Column 'A'
I want to insert an row at the position where I encounter Integer Value.

Here is my Excel snapshot
[image]

I have written a below code which identifies the Integer value in the column 'A' and it will insert a Row. But the problem is Even the insertion is happening at the blank spaces (eg: In Row number 4,8,9 and 14).
So can anyone tell me how to achieve the insertion of rows in only those rows where I have Integer.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()



 Dim UsedCell, MyRange, intCell
 Dim Cell_Text As String
 Dim Cell_Address As String


 UsedCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Set MyRange = Range("A2:A" & UsedCell)

For Each intCell In MyRange
Cell_Text = intCell.Offset(0, 3).Text
Cell_Address = intCell.Offset(0, 3).Address
FoundRow = intCell.Row

  If Not InStr(1, intCell.value, ".") > 0 And InStr(1, intCell.value, ".") <> "" Then
 Range(Cell_Address).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Select

     Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove


 Else

End If

Next intCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `InStr(1, intCell.Text, ".") > 0` if you want to use the value as it is shown.... also `InStr(1, intCell.value, ".") <> ""` will always be true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using inStr on a numeric value is a bit convoluted. Also be aware that Excel will interpret empty cells to a value of 0. Try something along these lines:

```
If Int(intCell.Value) = intCell.Value And intCell.Value > 0 Then
    Debug.Print "insert"
End If
```

In words: If the integer of the cell value equals the cell value (i.e. there are no decimals) AND the cell is greater than zero, do the insert code.

Comment: Thanks for the code @teylyn, now there is a new problem, everytime when I insert the row the IntCell Variable always points to the same range and it keeps on inserting. This happens when it finds the first Integer value, so it is not parsing to the next rows.

Comment: @KarthikPB This is because your IntCell is now the next incremented intCell. When ever you want to insert or remove data from a list/sheet always start at the end and work your way to the beginning.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen thanks a ton, it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question the OP had to @Teylyn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868050/how-to-insert-a-row-at-a-specific-positions#comment57476712_34868192), see basic script for running a `Loop`in reverse.

This example just sets a `Range` of Cells A1 to A10 and then activates them in reverse order.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopingInReverse()

    Dim MyRng As Range
    Dim MyCellRef As Long

    Set MyRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A10")

    For MyCellRef = MyRng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1

        Cells(MyCellRef, "A").Activate

    Next MyCellRef

End Sub
```